# Pre-processor: Expand a macro only once

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

Is it possible to have a macro expanded only once? In the following example, `MYCONCAT` is expanded to `func_1(10)`. I want it to expand to `func_BAR(10)`.

```
#define BAR 1  // included from a file I cannot change
#define FOO BAR

#define MYCONCAT2(c) func_ ## c
#define MYCONCAT(c, x) MYCONCAT2(c)(x)

MYCONCAT(FOO, 10) // is 'func_1(10)', but I want it to be 'func_BAR(10)'
```

Comment: You can `#undef BAR`

Comment: It is not that you want a macro expanded only once; each macro in the example is expanded only once: `MYCONCAT` to the text with `MYCONCAT2`, `MYCONCAT2` to `func_ ## c`, `FOO` to `BAR`, and `BAR` to `1`. What you want is for the macro replacement process itself to be limited.

Comment: I feel like we need more context here. Why is BAR defined as 1 if you don't want it expanded that way? What is the ultimate goal and use case of this strange contraption?

Comment: You can do this with enums instead of `#define` constants.

Comment: Can you include the file that defines `BAR` after the point where you use `MYCONCAT` instead of before it?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, that would work.

Comment: I apologize for not providing enough context. I have now realized that there is a simple solution for my concrete use case. Simply change `#define BAR` to `#define _BAR` and and remove the `_` from `func`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a macro expanded only once?

No, it is not possible to partially expand a macro.

Answer (score 2):

Include the file that defines `BAR` only after the last place where `MYCONCAT` is used (with something that expands to `BAR`) instead of before it.

Answer (score 2):

Simply change `#define BAR` to `#define _BAR` and and remove the `_` from `func`.

```
#define BAR 1  // included from a file I cannot change
#define FOO _BAR

#define MYCONCAT2(c) func ## c
#define MYCONCAT(c, x) MYCONCAT2(c)(x)

MYCONCAT(FOO, 10) // 'func_BAR(10)'
```